# Помощь в решении задачи построение раскрывающегося дерева методом рекурсии на js и json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
{
    data:[

            {itemId:1, itemName:"пункт №1", itemParentId:0},

            {itemId:2, itemName:"пункт №1.1", itemParentId:1},

            {itemId:3, itemName:"пункт №1.2", itemParentId:1},

            {itemId:4, itemName:"пункт №1.2.1", itemParentId:3},

            {itemId:5, itemName:"пункт №1.2.2", itemParentId:3},

            {itemId:6, itemName:"пункт №1.2.3", itemParentId:3},

            {itemId:7, itemName:"пункт №2", itemParentId:0},

            {itemId:8, itemName:"пункт №3", itemParentId:0},

            {itemId:9, itemName:"пункт №3.1", itemParentId:8},

            {itemId:10, itemName:"пункт №3.2", itemParentId:8},

            {itemId:11, itemName:"пункт №3.3", itemParentId:8},

            {itemId:12, itemName:"пункт №3.3.1", itemParentId:11},

            {itemId:13, itemName:"пункт №3.3.1.1", itemParentId:12},

            {itemId:14, itemName:"пункт №3.3.1.2", itemParentId:12},

            {itemId:15, itemName:"пункт №3.3.1.3", itemParentId:12},

            {itemId:16, itemName:"пункт №3.3.2", itemParentId:11},

            {itemId:17, itemName:"пункт №4", itemParentId:0},

            {itemId:18, itemName:"пункт №5", itemParentId:0},

            {itemId:19, itemName:"пункт №5.1", itemParentId:18}

    ]
}
```

пытался решить так но это неправильное решение:

```
var  listCategories = {
    data:[

        {itemId:1, itemName:"пункт №1", itemParentId:0},

        {itemId:2, itemName:"пункт №1.1", itemParentId:1},

        {itemId:3, itemName:"пункт №1.2", itemParentId:1},

        {itemId:4, itemName:"пункт №1.2.1", itemParentId:3},

        {itemId:5, itemName:"пункт №1.2.2", itemParentId:3},

        {itemId:6, itemName:"пункт №1.2.3", itemParentId:3},

        {itemId:7, itemName:"пункт №2", itemParentId:0},

        {itemId:8, itemName:"пункт №3", itemParentId:0},

        {itemId:9, itemName:"пункт №3.1", itemParentId:8},

        {itemId:10, itemName:"пункт №3.2", itemParentId:8},

        {itemId:11, itemName:"пункт №3.3", itemParentId:8},

        {itemId:12, itemName:"пункт №3.3.1", itemParentId:11},

        {itemId:13, itemName:"пункт №3.3.1.1", itemParentId:12},

        {itemId:14, itemName:"пункт №3.3.1.2", itemParentId:12},

        {itemId:15, itemName:"пункт №3.3.1.3", itemParentId:12},

        {itemId:16, itemName:"пункт №3.3.2", itemParentId:11},

        {itemId:17, itemName:"пункт №4", itemParentId:0},

        {itemId:18, itemName:"пункт №5", itemParentId:0},

        {itemId:19, itemName:"пункт №5.1", itemParentId:18}

    ]};

var list = '';
function parseCatRecursive(cat){
    cat.forEach(function(item){
        list+='<ul class="">';
        for(var key in item){
            if(key === 'itemName')
             list+='<li class ="" id=" ' + key +' ">' +item[key] + '</li>';
            if(key === 'itemParentId' && item[key].length !== 0){
                list+='<ul class="">'
                parseCatRecursive(item[key]);
                list+= '</ul>'
            }
        }
        list+='</ul>'
    });
}
parseCatRecursive(listCategories);
$('body').html(list);
```

Вообщем задача у меня такая Необходимо реализовать дерево средствами JS(native)+HTML+CSS3. Базовый принцип работы идентичен навигации по каталогам в проводнике Windows:

- у каждого узла, у которого есть дети, должна быть отдельная иконка-стрелочка с возможностью скрыть/развернуть его. Если детей нет, иконки для сворачивания быть не должно;
- количество уровней вложенности неограниченно;
- при клике, элемент должен подсвечиваться;

Уважаемые коллеги поскольку новичок сильно не разбираюсь в js но данную задачу хотелось бы решить. Прошу помочь если есть аналогичные решения то дать ссылки на них и по возможности давать подсказки в решении. Решать за меня задачу не нужно. Нужны грамотные советы.

Comment: сначала просто сверстай пример, без js. потом сразу будет видно что именно должен генерировать яваскрипт

Comment: такая структура получается http://jsfiddle.net/Radik_Zu/x0jxmc9q/

Comment: теперь css добавляй пример иконки для сворачивания, пример когда она есть когда нет, пример подсвеченой

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Radik_Zu/x0jxmc9q/ исправил

Comment: что-то css не вижу

Comment: забыл сохранить изменения ))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31445/discussion-between-grundy-and-radik-zu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прежде чем пытаться сразу написать генерацию на яваскрипте, нужно определиться со структурой, которую необходимо сгенерировать, а так же подумать над стилями.

Например:

```
<ul class="tree"></ul>
```

обозначим список, который хотим сделать деревом классом "tree".
Далее определимся с элементами:

1. внутри элемента должно быть содержание
2. значок для схлопывания/раскрытия вложенного дерева
3. вложенное дерево, если есть.

например, вот так

```
<ul class="tree">
    <li><a class="state">+/-</a><a>Текст</a></li>
    <li><a class="state">+/-</a><a>Текст</a>
       <ul class="tree">...</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Здесь первый тег `<a>` отвечает за свернутось/развернутость вложенного поддерева, второй - показывает название узла.

Можно так же добавить класс к самому узлу, и ориентироваться по нему - показывать или нет вложенное поддерево, например

```
<li class="collapse"><a class="state">+/-</a><a>Текст</a>
<li class="expand"><a class="state">+/-</a><a>Текст</a>
```

как вариант, в зависимости от класса можно также показывать скрывать тег `<a>` отвечающий за свернутось/развернутость вложенного поддерева.

В итоге, примерная структура может быть следующей:

```
<ul class="tree">
    <li><a class="state">+/-</a><a>Текст</a></li>
    <li class="expand"><a class="state">+/-</a><a>Текст</a>
       <ul class="tree">...</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Теперь можно переходить к яваскрипту:

судя по полученной структуре, должна быть простая рекурсивная функция, примерно такая в псевдокоде

```
function createTree(data, parent){
    var items = getItems(data,parent);
    if(items.length == 0) return null;
    var tree = createList().addItems(
        items.map(function(i){
            var item=createItem();
            var nestedTree = createTree(data, i);
            if(nestedTree){
                item.addTree(nestedTree);
            }
            return item;
        });
    )

    return tree;
}
```

Осталось только раскрыть определение служебных функций

- `getItems` - возвращает список дочерних элементов для выбранного узла
- `createList` - отвечает за создание списка, может как создавать DOM элемент, так и создавать строку, в зависимости от реализации
- `addItems` - добавлять список дочерних узлов в созданное дерево.
- `createItem` - отвечает за создание элемента списка, он же *узел дерева*, может как создавать DOM элемент, так и создавать строку, в зависимости от реализации
- `addTree` - добавляет поддерево в узел.

Ну и в самом конце можно уже подумать про функционал открытия/закрытия списка и выделения конкретного узла

```
.on('click', '.item',function(){// если кликнули по тексту
    $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active'); //удаляем со всех элементов кроме того по которому щелкнули класс active
    $(this).toggleClass('active'); // добавляем active если не было, убираем если был у текущего элемента
})
.on('click', '.state',function(){// если кликнули по свернуть/развернуть
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('collapse expand');//менять класс у родительского элемента (li) все остальное сделает css
})
```

Пример конкретной реализации можно увидеть ниже в сниппете:

```js
var listCategories = {
  data: [

    {
      itemId: 1,
      itemName: "пункт №1",
      itemParentId: 0
    },

    {
      itemId: 2,
      itemName: "пункт №1.1",
      itemParentId: 1
    },

    {
      itemId: 3,
      itemName: "пункт №1.2",
      itemParentId: 1
    },

    {
      itemId: 4,
      itemName: "пункт №1.2.1",
      itemParentId: 3
    },

    {
      itemId: 5,
      itemName: "пункт №1.2.2",
      itemParentId: 3
    },

    {
      itemId: 6,
      itemName: "пункт №1.2.3",
      itemParentId: 3
    },

    {
      itemId: 7,
      itemName: "пункт №2",
      itemParentId: 0
    },

    {
      itemId: 8,
      itemName: "пункт №3",
      itemParentId: 0
    },

    {
      itemId: 9,
      itemName: "пункт №3.1",
      itemParentId: 8
    },

    {
      itemId: 10,
      itemName: "пункт №3.2",
      itemParentId: 8
    },

    {
      itemId: 11,
      itemName: "пункт №3.3",
      itemParentId: 8
    },

    {
      itemId: 12,
      itemName: "пункт №3.3.1",
      itemParentId: 11
    },

    {
      itemId: 13,
      itemName: "пункт №3.3.1.1",
      itemParentId: 12
    },

    {
      itemId: 14,
      itemName: "пункт №3.3.1.2",
      itemParentId: 12
    },

    {
      itemId: 15,
      itemName: "пункт №3.3.1.3",
      itemParentId: 12
    },

    {
      itemId: 16,
      itemName: "пункт №3.3.2",
      itemParentId: 11
    },

    {
      itemId: 17,
      itemName: "пункт №4",
      itemParentId: 0
    },

    {
      itemId: 18,
      itemName: "пункт №5",
      itemParentId: 0
    },

    {
      itemId: 19,
      itemName: "пункт №5.1",
      itemParentId: 18
    }

  ]
};

function createTree(data, parentId) {

  parentId = parentId || 0;
  var items = data.filter(function(el) {
    return el.itemParentId == parentId;
  });

  if (items.length == 0) return null;

  var tree = $('<ul>').addClass('tree');
  tree.append(
    items.map(
      function(el) {
        var li = $('<li>').append(
            $('<a>').addClass('state')
          ).append(
            $('<a>').html(el.itemName).attr('id', el.itemId).addClass('item')
          ),
          nestedTree = createTree(data, el.itemId);

        if (nestedTree !== null) {
          li.append(nestedTree)
            .addClass('collapse')
        }
        return li;
      }
    )
  );
  return tree;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var tree = createTree(listCategories.data);
  
  $('#tree').append(tree)
            .on('click', '.item',function(){
                $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
            })
            .on('click', '.state',function(){
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('collapse expand');
            })
  
});
```

```css
ul.tree {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}
.active {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.state {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
}
.collapse > .state::after {
  content: '+';
}
.expand > .state::after {
  content: '-';
}
.collapse > ul {
  display: none;
}
.expand > ul {
  display: block;
}
.item {
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tree"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Идея в следующем: в цикле для каждого `itemId` строим узел, потом с помощью фильтра находим дочерние узлы и рекурсивно строим их.

```
function buildNode(item, cat) {
    var result = '<li id="'+item.itemId+'">'+item.itemName;
    var children = '';
    cat.filter(function(i){ return i.itemParentId == item.itemId; })
       .forEach(function(i) { children += buildNode(i, cat); });
    if (children.length > 0) {
        result += '<ul>'+children+'</ul>';
    }
    return result + '</li>';
}
```

Запуск построения узлов:

```
 var list = '<ul>';
 listCategories.data.forEach(function(item){
     list += buildNode(item, listCategories.data);
 });
 list += '</ul>';
```

Comment: забыл css классы нужный добавить :-)